# Two-way messaging between contentscript.js and another js file in a Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Apart from the usual files such as `contentscript.js`, `background.js` and so on, the Chrome extension I am building has a completely arbitrary file called `app.js` where most of the business logic is concentrated. I am organizing files like so to abstract most of the browser-independent logic into that app.js file and to reuse is for building extensions for other browsers.

I've declared that `app.js` file in `manifest.json`:

```
 "background": {
    "scripts": [
      ...,
      "scripts/lib/app.js"
    ]
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*"
      ],
      "js": [
        "scripts/lib/app.js",
        "scripts/contentscript.js"
      ],
      "run_at": "document_end",
      "all_frames": false
    }
  ]
```

Now, here comes the question. I can initiate communication between contenscript.js and app.js by running `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` or `chrome.runtime.connect` from contentscript.js (as described in the [docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging)). But I couldn't figure out a good way for the opposite way of communication, namely how to send messages from app.js to contenscript.js.
Documentation [discusses](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage) only sending messages from web pages, but that's not what I want to do. I want to send messages from one js file to another within the Chrome extension. `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` sent from app.js doesn't seem to register by contentscript.js.

**UPDATE:** Just to be clear, what I am asking about is how to establish communication between two or more js files declared in the "content_script" section of manifest.json. I can send messages from one file to the other (`contenscript.js` → `app.js`), but not from the second one to the first (`app.js` → `contentscript.js` or `app.js` → `background.js`). Which puzzles me, because app.js is declared in exactly the same section of manifest.json as contentscript.js is.

Comment: Yes it is possible. You can broadcast messages to any number of tabs from the background script so you just need to setup a background listener that will forward messages to other tabs. You need to show your event handling code too. When using common js files, I found I wound up with one common file for pages and one for the background as the requirements are slightly different.

Comment: wrap your message in *chrome.tabs.query* and use tab.id in callback for sending message to specific tab where your content script needs to receive it

Comment: Could you please take a look at the update to my question? Looking at the comments, I am not sure we are talking about the same thing.

Comment: Wait. I'm very confused. You have 2 copies of `app.js` which is probably not a good thing. Which instance are you trying to send from? To which instance?

Comment: Erm. Here is what I wrote in the paragraph immediately below the code block: "Now, here comes the question. I can initiate communication between contenscript.js and app.js by running chrome.runtime.sendMessage or chrome.runtime.connect from contentscript.js (as described in the docs). But I couldn't figure out a good way for the opposite way of communication, namely how to send messages from app.js to contenscript.js." Is this really completely different from my clarification in the update section?

Comment: You're saying `app.js` is browser-independent logic. Okay. Then your `background.js` and `contentscript.js` should be communicating, not `app.js` instances.

Comment: I have one app.js file. At the moment, I declare it both in the background section and in the content_scripts section. I can remove it from the background section of manifest.js; I don't really need it there. My problem is, if I declare app.js along with contentscript.js only in the content_script section, I still can't send messages to contentscript.js.

Comment: Within the same page, or cross pages?

Comment: Within the same page.

Comment: content scripts cannot communicate with **chrome.runtime.sendMessage** between each other. Only content -> background and other way around. If you need logic to run only in content script, make it one . If you need comunication between frames, reroute it throug background script, but you need to wrap message from background in **chrome.tabs.query**

Comment: Hey @vux777, I think you actually explained what my error was. I was thinking I was communicating with app.js declared in `"content_scripts"`, but I might in fact all have been communicating with `app.js` declared in the `background` section all that time. It explains part of the problems I was having. Although it does not quite explain why I couldn't send a message back from that `app.js` to `contentscript.js`. Hmm...

Comment: use  *chrome.tabs.query({active: true}, function(tabs) {
   chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {'your: "message"});
  });*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you have 2 scripts defined in the same content script "bundle" in the manifest.

This does not at all differ from just mashing the two scripts together into one `.js` file. They operate in the same context and share everything.

So, you can directly call functions and use variables from `contentscript.js` in `app.js` and vice versa within the same frame.

If you need to communicate across tabs (or frames within a tab), you'll need to use the background as a proxy. There is no direct function to send a message to another content script *context*.

Comment: You are very right, and I see now that I was very confused. I should just be able to call for functions defined in `app.js` from my `contentscript.js` instead of trying to call `app.js` by messaging to it. Something seems to be broken in my code though, so it's not working. Let me see if I can figure this out.

Comment: Yes, fixed it. Phew! So stupid of me! Thanks for clearing this stuff out.

Comment: Should I change the title of the question, do you think? To make it less misleading and to actually expose what the real problem was?

Comment: Just editing the title won't do. 1) No need to use "Update:" to denote changes; that's what edit history is for. 2) Your use of `app.js` in the manifest is confusing. Clean this up thoroughly.